# Container padding image aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to do a common trick, but I'm clearly doing something wrong as I'm not having the desired outcome. I'm trying to fill a container with padding using an image's aspect ratio, so it *should* make the container the same height as the image.

I read online that to get an image's ratio you have to do:

`height / width * 100`

### HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <img src="..." width="100" height="150" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.box {
  padding-bottom: 150%;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
}

.box img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h0k4kwxy/) showing what I've done.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `padding-bottom: 150%;` - 150% of what?

Comment: @connexo 150% (1.5) was the calculated aspect ratio.

Comment: Yeah, but internally when it comes to rendering, the browser has to find out how many pixels that 150% is. So off what should it calculate `150%`? % is obviously a `relative` size, so what does the 150% relate to?

Comment: If I knew that prior to asking I wouldn't have asked in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a container for your box as the `padding-bottom:150%` is 150% of the parent element:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.box {
  padding-bottom: 150%;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.box img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=100%C3%97150&w=100&h=150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding a container changes exactly *nothing* if that container does not have a defined `height` either.

Comment: @connexo, do you see a defined height in my code? do you see the massive red bit at the bottom like in the op fiddle? no? so it does change something

Comment: I'm confused as to how this works here, as I tried it on JSFiddle and it made no difference. Also what happens if you have multiple rows of boxes? See here: https://jsfiddle.net/h0k4kwxy/2/

Comment: @daryly, sorry, your inner box needs a percentage width (not a fixed width) and you can have as many as you want: https://jsfiddle.net/h0k4kwxy/3/

Comment: *"`padding-bottom:150%;` is 150% of the parent element."* And parent element's height depends on height of the content which is clearly influenced by the padding, so this is defining a circular dependency.

Comment: I see, I get it now.

Comment: @connexo stop trying to pick holes in the solution.  If you have a better solution then by all means why don't you answer.  This answer works for keeping the box to the aspect ratio of the image which is what the OP is trying to do.  It doesn't matter if it is circular or not if it works.  You really don't know your css very well for a senior front end develop, this is a well documented technique for responsive containers,  Have a read of this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/ and stop bothering me